# Probability functions convolution in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

There are N distributions which take on integer values 0,... with associated probabilities. Further, I assume 3 variables [value, prob]:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([ [0,0.3],[1,0.2],[3,0.5] ])
y = np.array([ [10,0.2],[11,0.4],[13,0.1],[14,0.3] ])
z = np.array([ [21,0.3],[23,0.7] ])
```

As there are N variables I convolve first x+y, then I add z, and so on. 
Unfortunately numpy.convole() takes 1-d arrays as input variables, so it does not suit in this case directly. I play with variables to take them all values 0,1,2,...,23 (if value is not know then Pr=0)... I feel like there is another much better solution.

Does anyone have a suggestion for making it more efficient? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a built-in method for this in Scipy; there's a way to define a custom discrete random variables, but those don't support addition. Here is an approach using pandas, assuming `import pandas as pd` and `x,y,z` as in your example:

```
values = np.add.outer(x[:,0], y[:,0]).flatten()
probs = np.multiply.outer(x[:,1], y[:,1]).flatten()
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': values, 'probs': probs})
conv = df.groupby('values').sum()
result = conv.reset_index().values
```

The output is

```
array([[ 10.  ,   0.06],
       [ 11.  ,   0.16],
       [ 12.  ,   0.08],
       [ 13.  ,   0.13],
       [ 14.  ,   0.31],
       [ 15.  ,   0.06],
       [ 16.  ,   0.05],
       [ 17.  ,   0.15]])
```

With more than two variables, you don't have to go back and forth between numpy and pandas: the additional variables can be included at the beginning.

```
values = np.add.outer(np.add.outer(x[:,0], y[:,0]), z[:,0]).flatten()
probs = np.multiply.outer(np.multiply.outer(x[:,1], y[:,1]), z[:,1]).flatten()
```

Aside: it would be better to keep values and probabilities in separate numpy arrays, if they have different intrinsic data types (integers vs reals).